# How can I recreate the databases view of Enterprise Manager using a SQL query?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Within enterprise manager 12c, when I go to Targets -> Databases, I see all my databases, but I don't quite understand how they arrive at this list. When I do a SQLplus query for this same information, I get a larger number (the same as the number of database instances when I look at "All Targets").

How can I restrict my SQLplus query so that I'm getting the same list of databases? I'm querying sysman tables like

mgmt$targets
mgmt$database_properties

and restricting by target_type.